# Can I delete a draft from Google Play Console in the middle of internal testing?

Tags: android-studio, google-play, google-play-console

I have messed up and need to start over. I have removed all testers from the "Internal Testing" tab, but my app is still listed as "in internal testing," so I cannot delete it. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete an APK/AAB that has been released to users. Even if you've removed access to new testers to download it, past testers may still have it on their device, so it will always appear in the Play Console.

You can however publish a new version (by increasing the `versionCode`) and create a new release. Testers will then see an update to the version which they can download overriding the version they currently have installed.

Comment: I have the same issue, but I uploaded an AAB into internal testing that had the wrong application name (e.g. `com.wrongname.app`). It won't let me upload an AAB with a new application name, and it won't let me delete the AAB.  How can I fix it to have the right application name?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Google will not let you delete apps (draft or published) if one person has ever installed the app (even if it was the developer testing the app in an internal test track). Even though [their help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9023647) states:

"You can permanently remove draft apps or games from Play Console."

This is simply not true. I had an email exchange with the Google developer help desk, and they told me:

*We can process an app deletion only if the app meets all of the following criteria:

- App must be in good standing (not rejected, removed, or suspended)
- App must have 0 lifetime installs
- App must not be in review
- App must be unpublished for 24 hours

... as your draft app has install statistics, we are not able to delete *

I had a similar issue to Alec, wanting to edit the application ID; the only way to do this is to create an entirely new app with the correct application ID. Since I couldn't delete the draft app with the incorrect app ID, I renamed it to start with xxxx, so I wouldn't get confused between the old app and the new app with the correct ID.